# ForgeRock OpenIG Sample (WordPressLogin.json) not working

Tags: openam

I follow the setup guide and when browse to
http://demo.forgerock.com:8080/wordpress/

I face below error, seem like the sample ip is no working.  Any help?

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /wordpress/. Reason:

    Connection to http://109.73.67.52:8080 refused

Caused by:

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://109.73.67.52:8080 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at org.forgerock.openig.handler.ClientHandler.handle(ClientHandler.java:203)
    at org.forgerock.openig.servlet.HandlerServlet.service(HandlerServlet.java:125)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.forgerock.openig.gateway.GatewayServlet.service(GatewayServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the provided config.json

```
{
    "heap": {
        "objects": [
            {
                "name": "HandlerServlet",
                "type": "HandlerServlet",
                "config": {
                    "handler": "DispatchHandler",
                    "baseURI":"http://109.73.67.52:8080"
                }
            },
```

The HandlerServlet which has a DispatchHandler which points to `http://109.73.67.52:8080`, where all request to http://demo.forgerock.com:8080 will dispatch to `http://109.73.67.52:8080`, which I believe was Wordpress setup by forgerock but has been shutdown. Therefore, you observed `Connection to http://109.73.67.52:8080 refused` error. The solutions is to replace with a valid `baseURI`, as well as  other information like `exchange.request.uri.path` etc